# If $f_n$ is in $L^1$ and $f_n$ converges to $f$, is $f$ in $L^1$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

This question might come off as basic to most of you, but this isn't basic to me.

If $f_n$ is in $L^1$ and $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^1$ ($||f_n-f||_1 \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$), does it necessarily imply that $f$ is in $L^1$?

Comment: $|f(x)| \le |f_1(x)| + |f(x)-f_1(x)|$ so $f$ is integrable, hence in $L_1$.

Comment: Is that really it? Add and subtract f_n and use triangle inequality of the L1 norm?

Comment: Well, you just need $f$ to be measurable and then integrable, so assuming measurability (implied by the existence of $\|f-f_n\|$), integrability follows from the other bound.